# How do I code this the smart way, Ajax/PHP

Tags: php, ajax, code-structure

I've got myself a little script that checks the validity of a link supplied by the user, making it safe to store in the database (safer at least) and to confirm it's a link to facebook.

Now I want to roll this code out for another links, changing parameters as and when needed so that links to people user profile on these sites work, bit I dont want to copy and paste the code another 5 times and then try and adapt the Ajax to work with it, if theres a better way to approach this.

This is my code, it can been seen working at www.vwrx_project.co.uk/test.php. It hopefully only accepts facebook.com/(something here) .

link_checker.php

```
<?php

function check_url($dirty_url) {
//remove anything before facebook.com using strstr() 
//clean url leaving alphanumerics : / . only -  required to remove facebook link format with /#!/
$clean_url = strstr(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9:/.?=]#i', '', $dirty_url), 'facebook.com'); 

$parsed_url = parse_url("http://www.".$clean_url); //parse url to get brakedown of components

$safe_host = $parsed_url['host']; // safe host direct from parse_url

// str_replace to switch any // to a / inside the returned path - required due to preg_replace process above
$safe_path = str_replace("//", "/", ($parsed_url['path']));

if ($parsed_url['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' && $parsed_url['path'] != '' && $parsed_url['path'] != '/') {
    echo "<a href=\"http://$safe_host$safe_path\" alt=\"facebook\" target=\"_new\">Facebook</a>";
} else if ($parsed_url['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' && $parsed_url['path'] == '') {
    echo "missing_profile1";
} else if ($parsed_url['host'] == 'www.facebook.com' && $parsed_url['path'] == '/') {
    echo "missing_profile2";
} else {            
    echo "invalid_url";
}
}
?>
```

Test.php

```
<?php
include_once ("includes/check_login_status.php");
include_once ("includes/link_checker.php");

// AJAX CALLS THIS LOGIN CODE TO EXECUTE
if(isset($_POST["L"])){
$dirty_url = $_POST["L"]; //user supplied link
//$dirty_url = "http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4"; 
    // if $dirty_url is blank
if($dirty_url == ""){
    echo "no link supplied";
    exit();     
} else {
    check_url($dirty_url);
}
exit();
}
?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testing</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>

function emptyElement(x){
_(x).innerHTML = "";
}

function cleanURL(){
var user_url = _("user_link").value;
var func = _("hidden").value;
if(user_url == ""){
        _("status").innerHTML = "Please provide a link before clicking submit";
    } else {
        _("submitbtn").style.display = "none";
        _("status").innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "test.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText == "no link supplied"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Submitted blank form data.";
                    _("submitbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else if(ajax.responseText == "invalid_url"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "The url supplied is invalid";
                    _("submitbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else if(ajax.responseText == "missing_profile1"){
                    _("status").innerHTML = "Please supply a link to your profile";
                    _("submitbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else if(ajax.responseText == "missing_profile2"){
                _("status").innerHTML = "Please supply a link to your profile";
                _("submitbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else{
                _("status").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("L="+user_url);
}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="status"></p>

 <form id="linkform" onSubmit="return false;">
    <input type="text" id="user_link">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden" value="Facebook">
    <button id="submitbtn" onClick="cleanURL()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you add an additional parameter which is the website you want to allow?

`function check_url($dirty_url, $websiteURL)`

Then update your function to use the `$websiteURL` variable instead of the hardcoded 'facebook.com'

Then when you want to have several different urls you can do this

`check_url($dirty_url, 'facebook.com');`

or

`check_url($dirty_url, 'twitter.com');`

Or are you wanting to be able to check for multiple sites in the single function? such as facebook.com and twitter.com

Comment: I'm not too sure, which is why I wanted to seek advice. I wanted to get a system in place where I can check the user supplied url for facebook, twitter, google+, instagram, youtube and their personal site if they have one, make sure that the main ones match the right format of link. 

My thinking was supply a form with 6 fields and when the form is submitted, check to see which fields if any were filled and then run the script

Comment: You could create an array inside the function which you can list all the allowed URLs. Then your code can just check if the URL pasted in matches any of the saved URLs in the array. You can use the ```in_array()``` function to do that.